# Optimization of Temperature converter in Java

Tags: java, optimization, converters

So I am struggling to get back to programming and I made this piece of code that converts Celsius to Fahrenheit and *vice versa*.

Its working fine but I must make it shorter. Can you make it work with less lines?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double temperature = 0.0;
    Double result = 0.0;
    
    String menuChoise = "1. Celsius to Fahrenheit \n2. Fahrenheit to Celsius";
    int anyChoiseMenu = 3;

    System.out.println("Chose a conversion");
    System.out.println(menuChoise);

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        try {
            anyChoiseMenu = sc.nextInt();
            if (anyChoiseMenu == 1) {
                System.out.println("What temperature you wanna convert: ");
                temperature = sc.nextDouble();
                result = (1.8) * temperature + 32;
                System.out.println("Result: " + result + " Fahrenheit");
                break;
            } else if (anyChoiseMenu == 2) {
                System.out.println("What temperature you wanna convert: ");
                temperature = sc.nextDouble();
                result = ((5 * (temperature - 32.0)) / 9.0);
                System.out.println("Result: " + result + " Celsius");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong number. Try again!");
                sc.nextLine();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Only numbers bro.");
            System.out.println(menuChoise);
            sc.nextLine();
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Yes, you can write it in less lines, but why do that? This is nice, build up logically, and quite well readable. It also does the job. Optimize for your fellow developers' time investment, that might include  your future self, not for the number of lines of code. Optimize only for the computer if the current performance is provably unstatisfactory.

Comment: if it works then it should be on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be running just fine. With a few tricks, as seen below you could cut a few lines of code.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String menuChoice = "\nChoose a conversion: \n1. Celsius to Fahrenheit \n2. Fahrenheit to Celsius";
        int menu;

        while (true) {
            System.out.println(menuChoice);
            try {
                menu = sc.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("Invalid input, only numbers are allowed!");
                sc.nextLine();
                continue;
            }

            if (menu >= 3) {
                System.out.println("Wrong number. Try again!");
            } else {
                System.out.print("What temperature you wanna convert: ");
                double temperature = sc.nextDouble();
                if (menu == 1) {
                    temperature = 1.8 * temperature + 32;
                } else if (menu == 2) {
                    temperature = (temperature - 32) / 1.8;
                }
                String grade = (menu == 1)? "Celsius": "Fahrenheit";
                System.out.format("Result: %.2f " + grade + '\n', temperature);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    scan.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Chose a conversion:");
        System.out.println("1. Celsius to Fahrenheit");
        System.out.println("2. Fahrenheit to Celsius");
        System.out.println("3. Exit");

        System.out.print("> ");
        int menu = scan.nextInt();

        if (menu == 1) {
            System.out.print("What temperature you wanna convert: ");
            double celsius = scan.nextDouble();
            double fahrenheit = 1.8 * celsius + 32;
            System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "Result: %.2f Fahrenheit\n", fahrenheit);
        } else if (menu == 2) {
            System.out.println("What temperature you wanna convert: ");
            double fahrenheit = scan.nextDouble();
            double celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8;
            System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "Result: %.2f Celsius\n", celsius);
        } else if (menu == 3)
            break;
        else
            System.out.println("Wrong number. Try again!");

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```